# How to find day of the week from a given date?

Tags: java, bluej

This is the code I am using to calculate the difference in days : 
Consider the 'n' value as the one I use as the count. After this I am using n%7 and using that remainder to get the day. The reference date I have used is 1.1.2000 which was a Saturday.
However, n is always giving 0. Why ? What's wrong ?

I CANNOT USE THE CALENDAR CLASS. IT HAS TO BE MATHEMATICAL.

```
public static void main(int d1, int d2, int m1, int m2, int y1, int y2)
{
    int n =0;
    for(;d1!=d2&&m1!=m2&&y1!=y2;n++)
    {
        if(m1==1 || m1==3 || m1==5 || m1==7 || m1==8 || m1==10 || m1==12)
        {
            if(d1==31)
            {
                m1++;
                d1=1;
                n++;
                if(m1>12)
                {
                    m1=1;
                    y1++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                d1++;
                n++;
            }
        }
        else if(m1==4 || m1==6 || m1==9 || m1==11)
        {
            if(d1==30)
            {
                m1++;
                d1=1;
                n++;
                if(m1>12)
                {
                    m1=1;
                    y1++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                d1++;
                n++;
            }
        }
        else if(m1==2)
        {
            if(returnLeap(y1))
            {
                if(d1==29)
                {
                    m1++;
                    d1=1;
                    n++;
                }
                else
                {
                    d1++;
                    n++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(d1==28)
                {
                    m1++;
                    d1=1;
                    n++;
                }
                else
                {
                    d1++;
                    n++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

Comment: You should use the `Calendar` class for that. And you should make your code more readable.

Comment: You code is totally unreadable. Some indentation would be nice

Comment: Fixed the code thing. Sorry. Indentation is up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is definitely a Big O way to solve this problem.  It looks like your for loop will terminate when any one of the day, month, or year match.  You probably meant to terminate when all 3 match, like

```
for(;d1!=d2||m1!=m2||y1!=y2;n++)
```

If you are open to alternate suggestions, how about

```
public static void main(int d, int m, int y)
{
   int n = (d + 5 * ((year - 1) % 4) + 4 * ((year - 1) % 100) + 6 * ((year - 1) % 400)) % 7;

   switch (m) {
        case 12: n += 30;
        case 11: n += 31;
        case 10: n += 30;
        case 9:  n += 31
        case 8:  n += 31;
        case 7:  n += 30
        case 6:  n += 31
        case 5:  n += 30
        case 4:  n += 31
        case 3:  n += 28;
                 if(returnLeap(y)) { n++; }
        case 2:  n += 31;
    }
    System.out.println(n % 7);
}
```

This is based on Gauss' algorithm (that dude was a genius).

Answer (score -2):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2013, 7, 1);
Date startDate = cal.getTime();

cal.clear();
cal.set(2013, 8, 1);
Date endDate = cal.getTime();

long diffDays = (endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
```

Comment: "I CANNOT USE THE CALENDAR CLASS. IT HAS TO BE MATHEMATICAL."